# LG Optimus G Pro - automatically turned on when charging

Tags: lg

I use OGP for last 2 months, everything is fine untill last night. I turned off the device and plugged in the usb and charge it. Suddenly the device is turned on. Try to turned it off again, but it just like restart. Back again to home screen. Root my phone about a month ago and no issue at all. Except last night. Rom is stock 10e.